# Linux, printing specific parts of a text document

Tags: text-processing

I want to print, for each line of a given document, the ﬁrst names and the ages of people (which are entries of the document). What linux command would I use? Hopefully based around grep using a regex pattern.

Example of input document:

```
Linda:F:Las Vegas, USA:18:telnet  
Steve:M:Leipzig, Germany:33:ftp
Henry:M:Milan, Italy:19:sftp 
Alice:F:Izmir, Turkey:32:pop3s
Robert:M:Verona, Italy:21:scp
Olga:F:Gorontalo, Indonesia:19:pop3s
Kimberly:F:Lille, France:25:ping
Henry:M:Oslo, Norway:26:ftp
Carol:F:New Delhi, India:23:pop3s
Thomas:M:New Delhi, India:32:http
```

Comment: What have you tried so far? Where are you blocked? You have to show some research effort if you want help from people here. :-)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use `cut`:

```
cut -d: -f1,4 file
Linda:18

Steve:33

Henry:19

Alice:32

Robert:21

Olga:19

Kimberly:25

Henry:26

Carol:23

Thomas:32
```

Answer (score 4):

You can use `awk`:

```
$ awk -F':' '{print $1,$4}' file
Linda 18

Steve 33

Henry 19

Alice 32

Robert 21

Olga 19

Kimberly 25

Henry 26

Carol 23

Thomas 32
```

Answer (score 1):

`sed 's/\([^:]*:\)[^:].*:\([^:]*\):.*/\1\2/' < file`

```
Linda:18
Steve:33
Henry:19
Alice:32
Robert:21
Olga:19
Kimberly:25
Henry:26
Carol:23
Thomas:32
```